# Variable declaration to store multiple values like full column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an requirement where I have to store the column value into an declared variable is it possible anyways. I understand that an variable can store only single value and not multiple values. But in my case I need it badly.

What I have here is to set the column if date value which is in INT has to be converted into Date column and save it in that variable to compare it.

I have some column with values like below

```
"A(B_CD_EE_FF_DFE)_ERT"
```

So i have to remove those two bracktes and process.

```
Set @Variable= (SELECT  replace (replace ( replace (SUBSTRING(TXMLFileName, CHARINDEX('(', TXMLFileName)
, CHARINDEX(')',TXMLFileName) - CHARINDEX(')', reverse (TXMLFileName)) ) , ')', '') ,'(' ,'') ,'.xml' , '') 

from 
tblXML )
```

Gives me error and  below gives answer as I select only top 1.

```
Set @Variable= (SELECT top 1  replace (replace ( replace (SUBSTRING(TXMLFileName, CHARINDEX('(', TXMLFileName)
, CHARINDEX(')',TXMLFileName) - CHARINDEX(')', reverse (TXMLFileName)) ) , ')', '') ,'(' ,'') ,'.xml' , '') 

from 
tblXML )
```

SO is there any known solution... ????? Thanks in advance

Comment: In first query result contains multiple rows and this causing for error. since multiple rows data can not possible to store in single variable. but this is not case in second query. in second query you are returning only one column value. and this single value can be store in single variable

Comment: Sql server have two data types that are desinged to keep multiple values - one is a table and the other is xml. You can declare a table variable or an xml variable. Other then that, your question is very unclear.

Comment: I don't know, where you *need these values in a variable badly*, but it might be enough to use your first query as `CTE`. If you still need help, please poste some (reduced) *real-world* examples and the expected output and some details, what you are going to do with this.

Comment: @ZoharPeled and there is `CREATE TYPE/TABLE/tempTable` and the need to know, if the value's usage is within the same scope...

Comment: @Nischey Anand post your sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Mansoor, I have couple of requirements which requires such data to be stored. One example is as shown above , however I have found an work-around for all . But I just wanted to know if multiple rows data can be stored in the  variable.anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A variable needn't just store a single value. You can create e.g. custom table types

```
CREATE TYPE MyCustomType AS TABLE (
    MyCustomTypeId INT,
    MyCustomValueColumn VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Or just declare a comparable table variable inline where needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tblXML table (TXMLFileName varchar(50))
insert into @tblXML values
('A(B_CD_EE_FF_DFE)_ERT'),
('(EE_FF_DFE)_ERT'),
('A(B_CD_EE)')

declare @tmp varchar(max)
SET @tmp = ''
SELECT @tmp=@tmp+ replace (replace ( replace (SUBSTRING(TXMLFileName, CHARINDEX('(', TXMLFileName)
, CHARINDEX(')',TXMLFileName) -1 ) , ')', '') ,'(' ,'') ,'.xml' , '')+''' '''
from 
@tblXML 

select ''''+@tmp
```

or you don't want to single row use this

```
SELECT ''''+ replace (replace ( replace (SUBSTRING(TXMLFileName, CHARINDEX('(', TXMLFileName)
, CHARINDEX(')',TXMLFileName) -1 ) , ')', '') ,'(' ,'') ,'.xml' , '')+''''
from 
@tblXML
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But this again gives me only one single row.

Comment: The updated query still gives me output in single row like below .B_CD_EE_FF_EE_FFB_CD_EE

 I have an table which has a column having thousands of rows in below format
 ie if the input values is 
'(A(B_CD_EE_FF_DFE)_ERT')
('(EE_FF_DFE)_ERT')
('A(B_CD_EE)')

then the expected output is removing brackets and is as below:
 
'**B_CD_EE_FF_DFE**'                              
'**EE_FF_DFE**'                                     
'**B_CD_EE**'